# GOOGLE SHEETS - Creating a table with running total using query function

Tags: pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, cumulative-sum

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to create an automated table shown on the bottom right-hand side based on sample data on the left.

The closest I can get is using the query function to create a pivot table (as shown on the upper right-hand side). However, I would like the table to show running totals instead of the USD value directly populated under specific days. Is there a way to achieve the desired output?

Comment: can same person have multiple usd entries per 1 day?

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 1):

a bit longer but the formula is way faster:

[image]

if you want it exact:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TEXT({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0), "×")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''")), 9^9, 2), 
 MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(IF((SEQUENCE(1, COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)*COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))>=
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)*COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)))*(INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0), "×")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''"),, 1)=
 TRANSPOSE(INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0), "×")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''"),, 1))), 
 INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0), "×")}, 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''")), 0)), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)*COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))^0)}, {"@", "d-mmm", "@"}), 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"))
```

[image]

---

non-english syntax:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TEXT({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0); "×")}; 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''")); 9^9; 2)\ 
 MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(IF((SEQUENCE(1; COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)*COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))>=
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)*COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)))*(INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0); "×")}; 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''");; 1)=
 TRANSPOSE(INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0); "×")}; 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''");; 1))); 
 INDEX(QUERY({A2:C; SPLIT(FLATTEN(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))&"×"&0); "×")}; 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''")); 0)); 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)*COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))^0)}; {"@"\ "d-mmm"\ "@"}); 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=transpose(query({"↓"&A1&"/"&B1&"→",transpose(sort(unique(A2:A)));
B2:B,arrayformula(mmult(1*(transpose(row(A2:A))<=row(A2:A)),IF(A2:A=transpose(sort(unique(A2:A))),if(C2:C="",0,C2:C),0)))},
"select Col1,max(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin("),max(Col",,sequence(1,counta(unique(A2:A)),2,1)))&") group by Col1 order by Col1 offset 1"))
```

non-English syntax

```
=transpose(query({"↓"&A1&"/"&B1&"→"\transpose(sort(unique(A2:A)));
B2:B\arrayformula(mmult(1*(transpose(row(A2:A))<=row(A2:A));IF(A2:A=transpose(sort(unique(A2:A)));if(C2:C="";0;C2:C);0)))};
"select Col1,max(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin("),max(Col";;sequence(1;counta(unique(A2:A));2;1)))&") group by Col1 order by Col1 offset 1"))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fe0DsbjDEow5Q8Xy70rdaXLsRgvksKcPb4eATcIlayo/copy

### Explanation

- First step, we will build a matrix with dates in rows `B2:B` and categories/persons in columns by `transpose(sort(unique(A2:A)))` and compute the cumulative inside the grid
- Second step, we will apply query to summarize the maximum value by date

### First step

The cumulative values ​​are obtained by the MMULT function between a square matrix composed of 1 and 0 along a diagonal and the values (0 if empty)

```
=arrayformula(mmult(1*(transpose(row(A2:A))<=row(A2:A)),IF(A2:A=transpose(sort(unique(A2:A))),if(C2:C="",0,C2:C),0)))
```

### Second step

The query will find the maximum of each column. Since we do not know in advance the number of columns (number of different categories / people), we will build the query `max(Col2),max(Col3),max(Col4)` in this way

```
="max(Col"&arrayformula(textjoin("),max(Col",,sequence(1,counta(unique(A2:A)),2,1)))&")"
```

- sequence function will produce a sequence of 2, 3 ... until the number of different categories/persons + 1
- note that we have added the date in column 1 at step#1, it's why we begin at #2

Comment: Thanks Mike. Unfortunately that didn't work for me - The error is "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." What is the use of "↓" and "→"? Apologies I am not too familiar with these symbols.

Comment: The "↓" and "→" symbols are only text ... take a copy of the sample spreadsheet I added in my answer.

Comment: @Bryan, you should post an example, what are your locale?